# Using Spring oAuth2 impl, is it possible to "downgrade" the scopes of an access token during a refresh-token grant?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I have two clients, one Public Client used by regular end-users logging in via our web page or native apps and one Confidential Client for our admin system. Both issues two JWT's, one Access Token and one Refresh Token.

The **Public Client** is not allowed to issue admin rights. The Access Token is short lived, and the Refresh Token has infinite life span.

The **Confidential Client** is allowed to issue admin scopes. The Access Token is short lived, and the Refresh Token lives 24 hrs.

Is it possible, using Spring Security and their oAuth2 implementation, to downgrade the admin user once the refresh token is expired? That is, once the user have been logged in for 24hrs, the user is not totally logged out, but on the next login he gets two new JWT's, one Access Token for regular user access and one matching Refresh Token for that access level. I guess I'm looking for some kind of hook in the Spring Security framework that allows me to handle token expiration in a customised way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>There's a sentence on your question that confuses me a bit, but I wanted to elaborate on other aspects so this did not fit in a comment.</sub>

> ... the user is not totally logged out, but **on the next login** he gets two new JWT's, one Access Token for regular user access and one matching Refresh Token for that access level.

What do you exactly mean with *on the next login*? My confusion here is that if the objective is not to logout the user, then there **won't** be a next login. I guess this could mean that almost to the end of the refresh token expiration you would want to do your downgrade request and use the still valid refresh token to get a new pair of tokens with less permissions.

According to the OAuth specification you can perform a refresh token request and ask the server for an access token that has less scopes than the one you currently have. However, it also dictates that if a new refresh token is returned, then that token needs to have the exact same scope as the refresh token included in the request.

Personally, for this scenario I would consider instead of downgrading tokens just ensure that in order to perform any administrator related operation the user must be an administrator **and actually provided his credentials** in the last 24 hours. You could accomplish this by tracking the date and time a given user actually performed a login (by providing their credentials) and then authorize administrator actions based on that value. This way you can increase the lifetime of refresh tokens for the confidential client and only force the administrators to login again if they want to perform a privileged tasks and their current tokens aren't fresh enough.

Finally, still on the subject of [refresh tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/) (with focus on the *security considerations* section)... when you say web app for the public client I'm assuming it's a browser-based Javascript application. If this is correct it's generally not recommended to use refresh tokens for these applications because refresh tokens are usually long-lived (in your case they seem to never expire) and the browser cannot ensure secure storage for them. This increases the likelihood of them leaking which would give an attacker access to the application for the lifetime of the token. You may have other constraints that make this security consideration not applicable, but I wanted to call your attention to it nonetheless.

Comment: With "next login" I actually ment "next interaction with the backend", sorry. I guess the fact that I cannot change the scope of a refresh-token really answers my question. You proposal is good, unless I get too many admin interactions. Then I would lose the benefit of a distributed authorization and the load on my account-service will increase. I may end up with session-caches again...   If not using refresh-token pattern, how can I keep a user logged in with a JWT and still making it possible to (simulate) a revocation of the token? How can I ban a user that logged in with name+pw?

Comment: One of the cons of using bearer tokens (self-contained JWT's) is that token revocation gets messier, RFC 7009 acknowledges this by stating that in these situations a backend interaction between the authorization server and the resource server  may be used in order to provide immediate access token revocation. I don't believe there's a standard that covers that interaction.